# Book recommendations for an euclidean geometry course

Tags: geometry, soft-question, euclidean-geometry, analytic-geometry, book-recommendation

I'm taking a euclidean and plane geometry course and the bibliography given to us is scarce. The course covers the next topics:

Trigonometry

Coordinate systems

Inversion in a circle

Poles and polars

Extension of the plane

Transformations of the plane

Would you recommend me books that covers such topics?
It's important to mention that the course is mostly proof-based

Answer (score 1):

Probably the most used book by students-contestants nowdays is EGMO of Evan Chen:

https://web.evanchen.cc/geombook.html

It covers all topics you mentioned and more.